# How to remove text between "matching" parentheses?

Tags: php, regex, string

When I read the alt(technically title)-text of [this XKCD comic](http://xkcd.com/903), I became curious whether every articles in Wikipedia eventually points to Philosophy article. So I began to make a web application that displays what articles it's "pointing" using PHP.

(PS: don't worry about traffic - because I'll use it privately and will not send too much requests to Wikipedia server)

To do this, I have to remove texts between parentheses and italics, and get the first link. Other things can be achieved using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), but remove texts between parentheses is the problem..

If there's no parentheses in parentheses, then I could use this RegEx:`\([^\)]+\)`, however, like [the article about German language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_language), there's some articles have overlapped parentheses(for example: `German (Deutsch [ˈdɔʏtʃ]  ( listen)) is..`), and above RegEx can't handle these cases, since `[^\)]*\)` finds **first** closing parentheses, not **matching** closing parentheses.  (Actually above case doesn't become a problem since there's no text between two closing parentheses, but it becomes a big problem when there's a link between two closing parentheses.)

One dirty solution I can think is this:

```
$s="content of a wikipedia article";$depth=0;$s2="";
for($i=0;$i<strlen($s);$i++){
    $c=substr($s,$i,1);
    if($c=='(')$depth++;
    if($c==')'){if($depth>0)$depth--;continue;}
    if($depth==0) $s2.=$c;
}
$s=$s2;
```

However, I don't like this solution since it cuts down a string into single characters and that looks like unnecessary...

Is there other ways to remove text in a pair of(matching) parentheses?

For example, I want to make this text:

```
blah(asdf(foo)bar(lol)asdf)blah
```

into this:

```
blahblah
```

but not like this:

```
blahbarasdf)blah
```

---

Edit : from a comment of Emil Vikström's answer, I realized that above approach(remove texts between parentheses) may remove a link containing parentheses. However, I still want the answer of above problem, since I met similar problem before and I want to know the answer...

So my question is still: how to remove texts between matching parentheses?

Comment: I started randomly at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betrayer_of_Worlds. After about 20 links I really did end up at Philosophy. `</anecdotal-evidence>` ;)

Comment: Yeop, you get into a philosophy/reality loop ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great! I am seeing someone with a problem which I experienced while cleaning up Wikipedia plain text content. Here is how you use it.

```
cleanBraces("blah(asdf(foo)bar(lol)asdf)blah", "(", ")")
```

will return

> blahblah

You can pass any type of braces. Like [ and ] or { and }

Here goes my source code.

```
function cleanBraces($source, $oB, $eB) {
    $finalText = "";
    if (preg_match("/\\$oB.*\\$eB/", $source) > 0) {
        while (preg_match("/\\$oB.*\\$eB/", $source) > 0) {
            $brace = getBracesPos($source, $oB, $eB);
            $finalText .= substr($source, 0, $brace[0]);
            $source = substr($source, $brace[1] + 1, strlen($source) - $brace[1]);
        }
        $finalText .= $source;
    } else {
        $finalText = $source;
    }
    return $finalText;
}

function getBracesPos($source, $oB, $eB) {
    if (preg_match("/\\$oB.*\\$eB/", $source) > 0) {
        $open = 0;
        $length = strlen($source);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $currentChar = substr($source, $i, 1);
            if ($currentChar == $oB) {
                $open++;
                if ($open == 1) { // First open brace
                    $firstOpenBrace = $i;
                }
            } else if ($currentChar == $eB) {
                $open--;
                if ($open == 0) { //time to wrap the roots
                    $lastCloseBrace = $i;
                    return array($firstOpenBrace, $lastCloseBrace);
                }
            }
        } //for
    } //if
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check out [recursive patterns](http://se.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php), which should be able to solve the problem.

When I read the comic I didn't have the willpower to get my head around recursive patterns, so I simplified it to find a link and only then check if it's in parenthesis. Here's my solution:

```
  //Fetch links
  $matches = array();
  preg_match_all('!<a [^>]*href="/wiki/([^:"#]+)["#].*>!Umsi', $text, $matches);
  $links = $matches[1];
  //Find first link not within parenthesis
  $found = false;
  foreach($links as $l) {
    if(preg_match('!\([^)]+/wiki/'.preg_quote($l).'.+\)!Umsi', $text)) {
      continue;
    }else{
      $found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
```

Here's my entire script: http://lajm.eu/emil/dump/filosofi.phps

Comment: +1 (because it's a great way to find the link), but this answer isn't what I wanted, since I do want the general way to remove texts between parentheses.. sorry :(

Comment: Yeah, I know it's sub-optimal since it doesn't even catch those `) link)` you asked for. I've taken a lot of shortcuts with my script. If you check my full script, you'll see how I remove nested `<table>...</table>`, which is a similar problem.

Comment: The worst thing is that there's also links containing parenthesis, and you don't want to remove those!

Comment: Uh oh.. I didn't think about that one.. :(